# What are some packages or methods that I can use to create JAWS-accessible LaTeX content?

Tags: packages, pdf, tools, accessibility

I'm looking for packages, external tools, and/or methods that allow me to create PDF (and Word  ?) files with LaTeX that are fully accessible and Section 508-compliant, and that can be read with screen readers like JAWS and Read & Write Gold 11.

Thanks!

P.S.: I'm using Notepad++, TeXworks, and TeXstudio

Comment: Maybe some of the links listed at http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latexresources.html#access might help.